# Add windows XP compatibility to CMake project from Qt Creator

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake, qt-creator, windows-xp

We need to setup, from Qt Creator, a CMake project with Windows XP compatibility (v140_xp) and Visual Studio 2015 compiler.

Actually we use Qt Creator CMake options `Generator: "NMake Makefiles"` and a build step "jom.exe *target*".
But I cannot find a way to add the Windows XP compatibility.

The only thing I can do, is via command line:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015" -t v140_xp -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/c/Qt/Qt5.6.3/5.6.3/msvc2015 ../src
```

But this creates Visual Studio 2015 solutions, not Qt Creator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what CMake needs to build Windows XP compatible code with non VS generators, sorry.

But if your CMake and creator is new enough (>= 3.9 for CMake, 4.4 for creator), then you should be able to use exactly the configuration you describe in creator and then just work with that build directory.

You will probably need to pass some extra flags to CMake to select the actual configurations you want to build though, otherwise Creator will display files several times (once for each configuration) and build times will also be longer (since you will build the same project in several configurations). In VS you can select the build types in the UI, but creator does not support that yet.